# Spring boot DispatchServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, web.xml

I've a spring boot project (executable jar with embedded jetty9).

I should register 2 different DispatcherServlet. I done in this way:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean sr = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/graniteamf/*");
    return sr;
}

@Bean
    @Order(2)
    public ServletRegistrationBean customDispatcherServlet() {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean sr = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/client/*");
        return sr;
    }
```

Unfortunally when I try to start the application I've this exception:

```
17/02/2015 18:24:04  INFO ApacheAsyncTransport:54 - Starting Apache HttpAsyncClient transport...
17/02/2015 18:24:04  INFO ApacheAsyncTransport:54 - Apache HttpAsyncClient transport started.
17/02/2015 18:24:04 DEBUG Application:173 - Inizializzazione identity
17/02/2015 18:24:04 ERROR DispatcherServlet:497 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:162)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at it.pianetatecno.gsmgateway.Application.main(Application.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 30 more
17/02/2015 18:24:05 ERROR SpringApplication:339 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at it.pianetatecno.gsmgateway.Application.main(Application.java:61)
```

I've two questions:

1. xml file for dispatcherServlet is mandatory?
2. in which folder Spring expect to find this file? I tried to put it into resources/WEB-INF but it doesn't work.

### Edited question

This is my main mathod in Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

public class Application {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

```
private static ApplicationContext context;

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.setShowBanner(false);
    context = app.run(args);
    app.setShowBanner(false);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *Why* do you need multiple servlets? The whole point of Front Controller is that you usually only need one.

Comment: Let's say I use only one DispatcherServlet. Also in this case I've the exception. Spring try to load the xml but I don't find the best practice to configure DispatcherServlet with Spring boot. Thanks

Comment: You just don't. At all. Include starter-web and Spring Boot does everything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need XML, but you do need to set the `ApplicationContext` on the servlet. Spring will do that for you if it is a `@Bean` (as it is in the `DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration` in Spring Boot), or I guess you can do it manually.

Comment: I added my main method on the original question. Is not so clear how make available this context to DispatcherServlet.

Comment: You can inject the application context as a method parameter in any `@Bean` method, or you can `@Autowired` it as a field or setter. This is standard Spring stuff (not Boot). Or you could do as I suggested and make the servlets into beans.

Comment: @Dave Is this always going to be the same `ApplicationContext` instance? Does boot have separate `(Web)ApplicationContext` instances, one for `DispatcherServlet`, one for `ContextLoaderListener`, one for etc.?

Comment: Spring Boot normally works with a single application context, but there's nothing stopping you from creating others if you ned them.